# UILabel shows Optional("P")

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UILabel where i set its texts property, and

```
        let firstCharacter: String = "\(user.name.characters.first)" ?? ""
        print(firstCharacter)
        userNameLabel.text = firstCharacter
```

Output: Optional("P")

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String Interpolating `user.name.characters.first` will always create a `String` because even if `user.name.characters.first` is nil then the interpolated string will be "nil".

The correct solution is

```
userNameLabel.text = "" //set the default value as ""
//if the name contains atleast one char then set it
if let firstCharacter = user.name.characters.first {
    userNameLabel.text = "\(firstCharacter)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap optional like so:

```
if let userName = user.name.characters.first {
   userNameLabel.text = userName
}
```

Answer (score -3):

IF you need to get first character you can use following code and it would be more correct than taking first character

```
let firstCharacter = user.name.substringToIndex(user.name.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
```

But note that you need to check before this call if the string is not empty.

Answer (score -4):

Print like this.

```
println(firstCharacter!)
```

it will work.